# How to convert a comma separated string of numbers to a number?

Tags: python, string, count, integer, concatenation

I want to convert a comma separated list of numbers into the number itself and number of times each number appeared appended at the end of appearance of that number, like this:

```
"2,5,6,9,2,5,8,2,7,1,1,1,4"
```

If this is the string, removing the commas will give :

```
2569258271114
```

But I want this:

```
256191252823711341
```

Let say the number 2 appeared 3 times, so i want to write 3 after the last appearance of number '2' which appears in the above number at `...823...`.
And so on.

I am stuck, I can do it the long way, but I need a short code. A pythonic way of solving the problem :) Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: Do you want the answer in string or in the integer format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use `Counter` from the `collections` module, and `str.find()`:

```
from collections import Counter

s = "2,5,6,9,2,5,8,2,7,1,1,1,4"
s = s.replace(',','') # Removes all commas
n = Counter(s) # Dictionary with different numbers as keys and their frequency as values

for a in n: # For every different number in n
    i = s.rfind(a) # Finds the index of the last appearance of the number
    s = s[:i+1]+str(n[a])+s[i+1:] # Inserts the frequency of the number on the right of the last appearance of it
    
print(s)
```

Output:

```
256191252812371111341
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :), You are the best. That was fast. Great. Marked as Right Answer now.